# jQuery: on click, change class and make it reclickable

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm trying to get this to work but just can't get it. So what I'm trying to do here is, when clicking link (.hidepage) it runs ajax and when it is complete, it will change that link name and class name (to > showpage). And what is not working is when clicking that link again for show page, it runs hidding again.

```
$('.hidepage').on('click', function(e){
var pageStatus = $(this).closest('tr').find('.pagestatus');
var button = $(this);
var pageID = $(this).attr('pageid');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: Jarvis.ajax_url + 'hidepage',
    data: { pageid: pageID },
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
        pageStatus.html('<span class="label label-default">Hide page</span>');
    },
    complete: function()
    {
        button.removeClass('hidepage').addClass('showpage').html('Show page');
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
    }
 });
});
```

And there is same code for showpage class for opposite action. Everything else is working. pageStatus is changing, link name is changing but action doesn't..
Thanks for all help! :)

Comment: Removing the class and adding a new class does not magically remove event handlers that are already attached to the element.

Comment: @MikeCheel There is code for opposite action for classname showpage. And Class names are changing..

Comment: Why do you put the switcheroo part in the complete event instead of success?

Comment: @MikeCheel Actually it was there but when playing around and testing whatever came in my mind it just left there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class showpage is dynamically added to elements. So, the event handlers should not be bound to .hidepage or .showpage, but to its parent. Example below:

Suppose the parent of .showpage is #showPageDiv,

```
$('#showPageDiv').on('click', '.showpage', function() {
    //handle show page
});
```

Similarly, do for .hidepage because that may be also dynamically added.

Comment: Yes sorry for delay, had to test it and this was solution! :) Needed to be specific for pointing element like div#showPageDiv to get it work. Thank you Sir!

Comment: whoa!! Dont address me as Sir pls. :) We are like a community here trying to help each other.